# PhpMyAdmin does not open in mozilla but work in chromium browser

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mozilla

I am using  **Ubuntu 12.04** Operating System. I have suddenly encountered a very strange problem. My **"PhpMyAdmin"** interface is not opening in **"Mozilla"**. But it is opening in another browser named as **"Chromium"**.

**Problem:**

When i try to open it from Mozilla, it shows me the following error:
[image] 
But in other browser **"Chromium"** it is working totally fine.
[image]

I searched about it on the internet. Everybody says it is a permission issue on the "config.inc.php" file. I have tried many solutions provided on the internet, but none of them worked.

**Question:**

My question is that if it is indeed a permission problem then why it is working in the "Chromium" browser but not in the "Mozilla" browser..

Comment: Is you question really why it is working in the "Chromium" or do you want to know how to get it working in Mozilla. Perhaps posting the config.in.php settings would give us more info.

Comment: I would guess you are logged in one browser and not logged in another. That forces different routing and, therefore, in one case the permission on `config.inc.php` is being checked and in other case—not. Nevertheless you should fix the problem with executing `chmod a-w config.inc.php` from the directory it belongs to.

Comment: The config setting `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` is likely set to "cookie" versus "config" and the login is being done automatically via the cookies in your Chromium browser. If you set it to "config", you can set the username and password via the config file.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your brower history, cache?

Comment: thanks a lot @mudasobwa it worked.. Now it is also working in Mozilla...

Comment: Nice to hear. I copy-pasted comment to answers for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are logged in one browser and not logged in another. That forces different routing and, therefore, in one case the permission on `config.inc.php` is being checked and in other case—not. Nevertheless you should fix the problem with executing

```
$ chmod a-w config.inc.php
```

from the directory it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an interpreter, try to set Mozilla as your default web brower in the settings of your interpreter.